# Breaking text file into multiple files mid-line

Tags: batch-file

I am receiving text files that have a series of messages in them.  I need to break these files into separate text files.  The files I receive look like this:

```
{1:data1}{2:data1}{3:{data1}}{4:
data1
data1
data1
data1 data data data
data1 data data data
data1
data1
-}{1:data2}{2:data2}{3:{data2}}{4:
data2
data2 data data data
data2
data2 data data data
data2
-}{1:data3}{2:data3}{3:{data3}}{4:
data3
data3 data data data
data3
data3
data3
-}{1:data4}{2:data4}{3:{data4}}{4:
data4
data4
data4
data4
data4 data data data
data4
data4
data4 data data data
data4
data4 data data data
data4
-}{1:data5}{2:data5}{3:{data5}}{4:
data5
data5
-}
```

I need to break the initial file into separate text files placed within the same folder at the curly brackets before the 1.  The text files produced as a result should end up looking like this:

```
{1:data1}{2:data1}{3:{data1}}{4:
data1
data1 data data data
data1
data1 data data data
data1
data1
data1
-}
```

There can be a dynamic number of messages in each text file.  I have found the following code and tweaked it but am having trouble getting it to do what I want.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET /a incnum=0
SET "searchstring={1:"
SET "found="
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (msg1.txt) DO (
 ECHO("%%a"|FIND "%searchstring%" >NUL
 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (SET found=Y&set/a incnum+=1)
 IF DEFINED found >>"file!incnum!" ECHO(%%a
)

GOTO :EOF
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will seperate the file into separate text files, named data1.txt - data`n`.txt. Obviously change `data.txt` in the batch file to the name of your data file.

```
@echo off

setLocal enableDelayedExpansion
set c=1

for /f "delims=" %%a in (data.txt) do (
    set line=%%a
    if "!line:~0,2!"=="-}" (
        echo -}>>data!c!.txt
        set /a c+=1
        if "!line:~2!" NEQ "" echo !line:~2!>>data!c!.txt
    ) else echo !line!>>data!c!.txt
)
```

You probably want to make the names a bit more dynamic, I can help you out with that if need be.

Comment: This works great! Except that I am noticing that the lines which had multiple words separated by spaces are only getting the first word in the new file.  I edited the post above to illustrate.

Comment: This works fantastic.  Thank you very much unclemeat!  This is exactly what I needed.